# Does this act have a name?

Tags: word-choice

I sometimes act silly like this that I pick up anything comprised of many smaller parts then leave my conclusion on how it is numbered or labeled.
Piece1: Mark knows my language
Piece2: Mark knows not
Piece3: Mark knows
Piece4: Mark knows not
Piece5: Mark knows
Piece6: Mark knows not
...
PieceN: Mark knows not :-(

Comment: Could you explain in more detail how this works? It sounds like a game young girls sometimes play: they pluck the petals off a flower, saying "he loves me" or "he loves me not" each time they pluck a petal. Whichever phrase they say as they pluck the final petal is supposed to be the truth. Wikipedia has an article about it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/He_Loves_Me..._He_Loves_Me_Not

Comment: I don't mean to use it for love, Thank you .

Comment: What I meant was, does the game I described and linked to sound similar to what you're talking about, even though you're not talking about love in your example?

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like an [Ip dip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ip_dip), being *a counting-out game often intended to select a person to be "it" (often, for the purpose of playing another game).* Or decide anything, akin to tossing a coin.

Common chants are [One potato, two potato](http://www.supersimplesongs.com/cd2-4.html), and [Dip dip dip my blue [or, little] ship](http://www.nurseryrhymes4u.com/NURSERY_RHYMES/Page_123.html). In these, as each word (or phrase) is uttered, a different person is pointed to, going round the participants. The last person indicated is the one selected.

As @Nicholas comments, a similar principle applies with young girls chanting [He loves me / He loves me not](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/He_Loves_Me..._He_Loves_Me_Not) alternately as they pull all the petals off a daisy. The version chanted on the last petal is supposed to be the truth.